# Can I use chartJS for drawing a stock map with rectangle?

Tags: chart.js

I'm looking for a solution to represent a map of a stock with rectangles like on the image just below. Is it possible with ChartJS or should I use another library?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/afpv5.png)

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can create your own custom charts

Comment: How can I do this ?
For the moment I use the annotations in block

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/developers/charts.html

Comment: Sorry but it don't help me. How can I tell chartJS to place a rectangle with its dimension (width, height, x, y)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [box annotations](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/guide/types/box.html) from `chartjs-plugin-annotation`.

Please take a look at below runnable code and see how it works.

```js
const rectangles = [
  { x: 2, y: 2, width: 8, height: 5 },
  { x: 2, y: 9, width: 8, height: 5 },
  { x: 2, y: 16, width: 8, height: 5 },
  { x: 2, y: 23, width: 8, height: 5 },
  { x: 12, y: 2, width: 5, height: 5 },
  { x: 12, y: 9, width: 12, height: 7 },
  { x: 25, y: 11, width: 8, height: 4 },  
  { x: 18, y: 2, width: 8, height: 5 },
  { x: 16, y: 26, width: 16, height: 8 }
]

rectangles.forEach(r => {
  r.type = 'box';
  r.backgroundColor = 'rgba(0,180,0,0.02)';
  r.borderColor = 'rgb(0,180,0)';
  r.borderWidth = 1;
  r.borderRadius = 4;
  r.xMin = r.x;
  r.yMin = r.y;
  r.xMax = r.x + r.width;
  r.yMax = r.y + r.height;
});

new Chart('myChart', {
  type: 'scatter',
  options: {
    plugins: {
      annotation: {
        annotations: rectangles
      }
    },
    scales: {
      x: {
        min: 0,
        max: 35
      },
      y: {
        min: 0,
        max: 35
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-annotation/1.0.2/chartjs-plugin-annotation.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```